# my text files no longer in project still show up on phone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am getting old files in my documents directory and not sure why.

On the simulator it works as expected.  I can update the files no problem.  I  just delete the app. from the springboard and rebuild.  I can easily verify the files are the correct ones.

But, when running on the iPhone, old versions of the files show up.  I do always delete the app of course.  And if I go to the project and delete the files and verify in the build phase that they are not included, they still show up on the iphone.

I have rebooted the mac and the phone, no change.

I even found under organizer how I can download the files from the iPhone and they do show the old files, but I am not sure how they got there as I don't think I am asking for them to be copied...

thx for any suggestions!

Comment: check in your code that are you making a copy of file and saving it to document directory if the file is not found at the path.???

Comment: Have you tried `clean` as well? Sometimes Xcode will store a copy of the app for faster build times.

Comment: thanks.  I do copy the files into the docs directory.  I can comment this out and they do not copy.  It seems like xcode is coping the files from a different directory than I think...I'll try and look to see if there is a way to find the .make file and see how it does it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding the compile output, I saw that xcode was copying from a directory called "DerivedData" and then I found posts about possible issues/bugs.

[Here is a link to the fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4)